# Backbone: appending views results in collapsed views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm splitting a collection into collections based upon an event date. I then want to append each of these grouped dates to the html so views will show up together based upon date. However, I'm getting the views appended but all collapsed on top of each other. They are literally on top of each other :(

This is my collectionView for everything render. Initial content is the div I want to append all the dayViews into.

```
render: function(){
    var groupedModels = this.collection.groupBy(function(eventItems){
            return eventItems.get('date');
        }),
        view = new eventCollectionView({
            collection: this.collection
        });

    _.each(groupedModels, function(group) {
        var dayView = new dayCollectionView({collection: group});

        $("#initialContent").append(dayView.render().el);
        $("initialContent").append("<br>");
    });
}
```

This is my day view, although the tag is already a div, I added an extra to see if it would make a difference, it doesn't. The eventView is a a handlebars template created isotope.js card. (just a pretty html card)

```
render: function(){
    var date = this.collection[0].get('date');

    this.$el.append("<h2>" + date + "</h2><div>");
    for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {
        var view = new eventView({model: this.collection[i]});

        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    }
    this.$el.append("</div>");
    return this;
}
```

When I don't split my collection into separate day collections, it appends perfectly fine. However, when I split it into separate collections and append those, the problems start appearing. Any ideas for this collapse?

Normally should be

```
[]
[]
[]
```

But now it's like

```
[]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the code really say `$("initialContent").append("<br>");` or is it `$("#initialContent").append("<br>");`? Also, `append` doesn't simply append text, it appends DOM nodes so appending separate `'<div>'` and `'</div>'` strings doesn't do what you probably think it does.

Comment: It says #initialContent, sorry forgot a #. So when a dayView appends the eventViews, the event Views are full handlebars templates. However, dayView is not. How should I go about adding dayView, which is comprised of several divs but nothing else?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal functional demo?